# How to find blurry areas in an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, blur

I am looking for a method to detect blurry areas in an image. I want to be able to select areas that are blurry. The most interesting is the motion blur.

For example: I made a photo of moving coin and want to detect blurred areas from left and right
[image: moving coin]

Another one:
[image: moving car]

I tried several methods and the gradient search turned out to be the best. Here the result:

[image: gradient of image]

But this method is absolutely not suitable for a non-uniform background. And I can't find blurred areas on photo with car

used code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import blure as bl


def put_mask(image, mask):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return cv2.filter2D(src=gray, ddepth=-1, kernel=mask)

width, height, x, y = 550, 400, 50, 100
img = cv2.imread("car.jpg")
image = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

mask_1 = np.array([ [1, 0, -1],
                    [2,  0, -2],
                    [1, 0, -1]])

mask_2 = np.array([ [1, 2, 1],
                    [0,  0, 0],
                    [-1, -2, -1]])

masked_1 = cv2.filter2D(gray, ddepth=-1, kernel=mask_1)
masked_2 = cv2.filter2D(gray, ddepth=-1, kernel=mask_2)
masked = cv2.bitwise_or(masked_1, masked_2)


cv2.imshow("edges", image)
cv2.imshow("grad", masked)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```